# Initialize static const multidimensional array with inferred dimensions inside class definition

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Since C++11, one can initialize static const built-in types inside a class definition, like so:

```
class A {
public:
    static const unsigned int val = 0; //allowed
};
```

However, doing this in Visual C++ 2013 with an array gives me an error telling me that this is not allowed:

```
class B { 
public:
    static const unsigned int val[][2] = { { 0, 1 } }; //not allowed
};
```

The error message simply reads "a member of type const unsigned int [][2] cannot have an in-class initializer."  Instead, I'm forced to do the following:

```
class C {
public:
    static const unsigned int val[][2];
};

const unsigned int C::val[][2] = { { 0, 1 } };
```

This is unfortunate because I have code which relies on the size of val, and I want to be able to change the contents of val without having to remember to go back and change a constant somewhere.  Is there a different way of doing this that allows me to use `sizeof` on `val` from any point in the file below the declaration?

Comment: So exchange the constant for an expression that actually obtains the size of `val`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your array must be a **constexpr** (clang and gcc specify it in their error messages) :

```
class B { 
public:
    static constexpr const unsigned int val[][2] = { { 0, 1 } };
    //     ^^^^^^^^
};
```

See it working [here](http://ideone.com/TlSUDP).

[Visual Studio CTP 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151) (a "beta" version, that should be avoided for production) provides support for `constepxr`, which should be available in future releases, too.

**EDIT :**

If your compiler does not support `constexpr` (hopefully for you, not for too long), then you cant do in-class initialization of your static array, and must do the old way :

```
class C {
public:
    static const unsigned int val[][2];
};

const unsigned int C::val[][2] = { { 0, 1 } };
```

If your array type is complete (if you declare all the array dimensions), then `sizeof` can be applied (the compiler knows how many elements to expect) :
;

```
class C {
public:
    static const unsigned int val[2][2];    // Specify all dimensions.
    void foo() { cout << sizeof(C::val); }  // OK
};

const unsigned int C::val[][2] = { { 0, 1 } , { 2, 3 } };

int main() {
    C c;
    c.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately visual studio doesn't support the constexpr keyword yet.

Comment: VS2013 CTP has it : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41151 , you should upgrade yours.

Comment: In regards to the above comment, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2010/06/14/what-is-a-community-technology-preview-ctp.aspx) may be relevant in deciding whether or not you feel comfortable using a CTP. I wouldn't necessarily say that the OP should be advised that he "should" upgrade, as a CTP is not guaranteed to be release quality, and is subject to change (which could in theory cause problems when a future release is used).

Comment: @NmdMystrey : "Community Technology Previews (CTPs) are early, prerelease versions of the next major release of Visual Studio. CTPs provide early adopters with an opportunity to try out the new and improved product features, and the ability to share feedback with the product team."

Comment: @quantdev CTPs are not licensed for production use, or even hobby use for that matter. They are only licensed for testing use. As such this is not an answer.

Comment: Back in the real world, a "beta".